# How to access the API controller methods through postman through HTTPS(local cetificate) when site is hosted?

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api, ssl-certificate, iis-8

I have a website which built with **ASP.Net MVC4** and **Web API 1** which is hosted in **IIS 8**(Windows Server 2012). I have created a local SSL certificate from **Create Self-Signed Cetificate** in IIS for testing purpose. But I cant access the API controller methods through postman through HTTPS. Please help me on this.

The SSL port is 443. I requested the web api request as http://[ServerName]:443/Employee/david

Comment: Firstly try https://[ServerName]:443/... on chrome and go on your web site. Secondly write https://[ServerName]:443/Employee/david on postman.

Comment: I coudn't access from the both when hosting from IIS with certification. But when hosting from VS without certification I can retrieve data from chrome or postman.